# What is the difference between heroku git:clone -a <app> and git clone <heroku-git-url>?

Tags: git, heroku, web-applications, clone

I deleted the local repo of my heroku app, then I wanted to clone it, so normally I use `git clone`, which worked in this case:

`git clone https://git.heroku.com/<app-name>.git`. However, in the settings of my app on Heroku's dashbord, it says I should use `heroku git:clone -a <app-name>` (this requires Heroku CLI which I already have installed.

So far I have tried cloning the my heroku app repo in both of the ways mentioned (`git clone...` and `heroku:git clone -a...`). In both cases it worked and I got my source code properly cloned.

In both cases `node_modules` was not cloned, which is understandable since I run `npm i` to install the needed ones specified in the `package.json` file. The question is: what is the difference between these two ways of cloning? I push my code using `git push heroku master` and that also works fine. My understanding so far is that there are no differences between the two mentioned ways of cloning a repo.

*Please note that there is no github involved in this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`heroku git:clone`](https://github.com/heroku/cli/blob/4644413ce92a66bd06cca3a13d4658b1255bc8f2/docs/git.md#heroku-gitclone-directory) command has its source in [`packages/git/src/commands/git/clone.ts`](https://github.com/heroku/cli/blob/eacf5bc515699f96e4f42e2501ae9cc3e7f6a41e/packages/git/src/commands/git/clone.ts), and, [from the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app), mainly adds a `heroku` Git remote to simplify future pushes

So check your `git remote -v` in both: you will see the difference.

Comment: Nice, I cloned both in seperate folders and indeed there was a difference (with git, `git remote -v` gave me `origin` whereas with heroku it gave me `heroku`). I believe I got my answer now: the primary difference is that the using heroku simplifies future pushes. Neat, thanks!